# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: android, exception

This is the error log:

```
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@45b69850 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-07 11:33:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(5612):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
```

And I know it is because of bad reference, I get the context through getContext() method(The dialog is not in any activity)

So I can't use XXXActivity.this to get the right context.  so what should I do?

Comment: show your code where u are creating or showing Dialog

Comment: try `getApplicationContext()` once.

Comment: Because there is no activity context available at that time to show dialog or dismiss dialog

Fix:

if(!isFinishing()){
 //show your dialog
  dialog.show();
 //dismiss your dialog
 dialog.dismiss();
}

Comment: @Ashok works like charmed

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem.I have used tab bar for this Just put `getParent()` instead of `youractivity.this`.

I hope this will help someone.